# ASP.NET deploy/build/publish website to local disk with SQL

Tags: asp.net, build, webforms, web-deployment

I don't know how to do that. This is my first project in Visual web developer and I never did that. My webform is connected (create, delete & edit) to SQL server and everything is working from the Visual web developer but how to export web project to be functional from local disk?
P.S.Only video on ASP.NET site that describes that doesn't work. Also Build web site does nothing.

Comment: Do You want to Publish A Project On Server or Move A copy To another Computer

Comment: I know I can copy it with Website/Copy website but I am still stuck with non-working aspx (even if I am starting that file in Firefox from the same PC where is developed -> XML Parsing Error), I need to publish it (to local hard drive) detach database from SQL server to standalone database file and to be able to start that from any PC. Is this possible?

Comment: if you want to Export it On other Computer then You can Copy All files(including Solution .sln) so from that Solution You can Open That project Into Other PC.In the case of database You can Backup and Restore easily

Comment: I don't want open it as a project but as a website, like when you save/download website for offline browsing.

Comment: then simply Publish Web Site on Your Local Disk And Install IIS that means Configure Your Local Computer as 'Web Server'

Comment: There is no publish option in Build menu nor in right click on project in Solution Explorer?